# Eclipse xdebug session never completes and holds on 48%

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

When i tried to debug file it's hold's on 48% and comuniacate wrote says: Waiting for Xdebug session... 
I am trying to get xdebug working with Eclipse Neon.1a / php (on xampp windows 7). I have verified that xdebug is enabled in `phpinfo();` I have `remote_debug=On`.
I have installed xdebug with https://xdebug.org/wizard.php hints.
My `php.ini` file:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/path/to/xdebug.so(.dll)
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_log=/path/to/xdebug_remote_log
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

I tried to use `remote_port=9000` but problem doesn't perish.
In `php.ini` i have also commend:
`zend_extension = D:\Serwer\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14.dll`
i tried to coment one line of zend_extension or another.
I have good settings in eclipse xdebug settings.
This is my first post on forum please be tolerant :)

Answer (score -1):

you need to check the xdebug_remote_log, I got the same issue.
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:19006.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
this is the error printed by xdebug.

Comment: It would help better if you post more descriptive and better-formatted answers.